# Google Firebase Angular Firestore switchMap - Firebase Error DocumentReference.set()

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm trying to setup an Angular Firebase app where the user data that I want to share with the App is stored in the Firestore Database. I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError:
>   [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with
>   invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field role)

My data is setup as follows:

[image]

My user service is setup like this: 
auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import {
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFirestoreDocument
} from '@angular/fire/firestore'

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from './user.model';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { faGameConsoleHandheld } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {
        //This is how we're getting into the firestoreDB        
        this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
          switchMap(user => {
            if (user){
              console.log("user from constructor", user)
              return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
            } else {
                console.log("returning null")
                return of(null)
            }
          })
        )
              } //end constructor

  private updateUserData(user){
    //sets user data to firestore on login
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`)
    console.log("userRef", userRef)
    const data = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      role: user.role,
      thursdayCampaign: user.thursdayCampaign,
      menagerieCoast: user.menagerieCoast
    }
    console.log("role:", user.thursdayCampaign)
    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true})
  }

  async emailSignin(value){
    const provider = new firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider();
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
    return this.updateUserData(credential.user)
  }
```

user.model.ts:

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName?: string;
  role: string;
  thursdayCampaign: Boolean;
  menagerieCoast: Boolean;

}
```

I've narrowed down the problem that is creating the error, the app is returning null from this.user$ in the constructor, but i'm not sure why it's doing that. I thought that setting AngularFirestoreDocument would cause it to access that property but it is not. You can see I have some console log functions sprinkled throughout the code. The "returning null" is getting returned when I run my function,

Answer (score 0):

The error message (emphasis mine):

> Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. **Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field role)**

is telling you that you passed an undefined value for the `role` field.  That means you have an undefined value in `user.role`.  We can't see why that is here, so you'll have to debug it by finding out where that `user` object comes from.

Comment: the user object is coming from google firebase's user profile. I'm aware role is undefined because it's not an object in firebase's user, which is why I am attempting to use switchMap to pull the user data from my firestore instead of google's backend. You can see from the fire store excerpt I attached that role is defined in the firestore database.

Comment: I edited the post with my user.model.ts which is I'm wondering what you were asking about.